# Variable at start of namespace (or equivalent)

Tags: struts2

I am trying to create URLs that look like `http://localhost:8080/app/client/shared-namespaces-and-actions`:

- “`/app`” would be the context root.
- “`client`” would actually be a variable, replaced by the actual client version/interface of the application, such as
  “john” (i.e.:
  `http://localhost:8080/app/john/namespaces-and-actions`).
- “`/shared-namespaces-and-actions`” would be packages/actions
  accessible under one or more clients (such as “/about/contact”, or
  “/products/73/edit”).

Ideally, a URL could entirely omit the “client” component, and so that for actions where it makes sense some sort of combined view could be displayed. For example “`/app/`” would display links to the client versions, whereas the client’s “`/app/client/`” would have what that client wants on their homepage.

This variable “client” component is what I have a question about.

Thus far, I have been using a query string parameter to handle the client selection, rather than part of the URL path. However, this has some obvious issues for things like bookmarks, as I always have to pass the client parameter in the query string (not attractive), else bookmarks will fail.

Is there an easy way to make this change? It seems like what I want is a wildcard in the namespace, as I do with actions, but the documentation doesn't seem to support that as a possibility, nor did experimentation. I already use packages to set namespaces, interceptor stacks, and to group related actions in the struts.xml file, so it would not be trivial to change all actions to be under the "/" namespace package with an additional wildcard for the client.

An option I was looking at was to extend the class `DefaultActionMapper`, and override the method `parseNameAndNamespace(String, ActionMapping, ConfigurationManager)`, removing the client component of the URI (if it exists), and then passing that modified URI to the parent implementation. However this has a number of issues, such as breaking all links, form targets, and redirects. I expect fixing the links/forms would be annoying to fix, but not impossible, but I'm not sure if the same would be true of redirects.

I am using 2.3.16.3.

---

struts.xml:

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="namedVariable"/>

    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="" />

    <package
        name="poc-default"
        extends="struts-default"
        strict-method-invocation="true">
        <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        <default-action-ref name="http404" />
        <action
            name="http404"
            class="poc.DefaultAction">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/http404.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

<package
    name="root"
    namespace="/"
    extends="poc-default"
    strict-method-invocation="true">
    <action
        name=""
        class="poc.DefaultAction">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/home.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action
        name="clients"
        class="poc.DefaultAction">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/client-select.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Using the struts.xml above, "`http://localhost:8080/poc/`" goes to the home page, and "`http://localhost:8080/poc/clients`" goes to the client selection page.

I then replace the package "root" with the following (added named wildcard to namespace):

```
<package
    name="root"
    namespace="/{uriClientString}/"
    extends="poc-default"
    strict-method-invocation="true">
    <action
        name=""
        class="poc.DefaultAction">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/home.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action
        name="clients"
        class="poc.DefaultAction">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/client-select.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Now, neither action is mapped by the URLs "`http://localhost:8080/poc/john/`" and "`http://localhost:8080/poc/john/clients`".

Comment: If you familiar with wildcard mapping why did you ask this?

Comment: @RomanC I am familiar with wildcard mapping for action names, but not with package namespaces, I didn't see any documentation indicating it was possible, and my attempt at inserting a wildcard into the namespace failed. My hope is to not have to flatten all of my packages into a single package, with each action name duplicating what its current package namespace has with regards to path, just to get wildcards at the start of the path (namespace) instead of the "end" (action name). So, I am hoping that there is, indeed, some way to have a wildcard/variable in/before the namespace.

Comment: You should post a code you've tried and errors.

Comment: I'm not sure the namespace route would even be the way to go about this; you don't really want different namespaces, AFAICT. Changing XML configs in this matter *should* be trivial using any reasonable XML manipulation technique; if using annotations, not so much. I have a couple of ideas, but none I really like yet.

Comment: @RomanC I have edited the question to include a minimal struts.xml file that works before adding wildcards to the package namespace, and the attempt to add wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Having given Dave Newton's comment some thought, I believe that he is correct that I was going about solving my problem (optional client selector prefix to URL) is probably not how I should be going about this.

URL rewriting seems like a better (and possible) choice, and instead putting the client into context via an attribute of the request. I have created a filter that appears before the Strut 2 filter in web.xml:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    final String requestServletPath = httpRequest.getServletPath();

    // Obtain set of client strings here.
    final List<String> clients = Arrays.asList("john");

    String newServletPath = null;
    for (String client : clients) {
        final String toCheck = "/" + client;
        if (requestServletPath.equals(toCheck) || requestServletPath.startsWith(toCheck + "/")) {
            /*
             * Put client into context here, {@link HttpSession#setAttribute(String, Object)} or
             * {@link ServletRequest#setAttribute(String, Object)}.
             */
            request.setAttribute("uriClientString", toCheck);
            newServletPath = requestServletPath.substring(toCheck.length());
            break;
        }
    }

    if (newServletPath != null)
        request.getRequestDispatcher(newServletPath).forward(request, response);
    else
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

It was also necessary Struts 2's filter mapping to support forwards:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Unfortunately, it is necessary to rewrite the generated URLs to include the client prefix if it is being used, since otherwise Struts2 will just start from the actual namespace:

```
<s:a namespace="%{#request.uriClientString}" action="">Home page</s:a>
```

Finally, it is also necessary to rewrite the redirects to include the client prefix if it is being used, since, once again, Struts2 will just start from the actual namespace:

```
<action name="re">
    <result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="namespace">${#request.uriClientString}</param>
        <param name="actionName">clients</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

This is not as easy to implement as I was hoping at the outset, but it does seem like it will meet my needs once everything is updated.

I will accept this in a couple of days if nothing better is suggested.